# How to call three function within one function in javascript each function should be called after finishing first

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call three function within one function in javascript each function should be called after finishing first function which receive some value by user..

javascript code:

```
function abc(){
    var ans  = ask(); /// contain html custom confirm with button
    if(ans == true)
    {
        do_action();
    }
    else
    {
        refuse_action()
    }
}
```

Actually I want to create my own javascript confirm dialog using designing in html.

I have create two button in it with name Yes or No

I want to call do_action function if I click on Yes or  refuse_action if I click on No button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your problem..?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Provide a jsfiddle maybe

Comment: Yes. my question is not clear here..Let me explain.

Comment: Yes. my question is not clear here..Let me explain.... My problem is that I want to create my own confirm dialog (alert and confirm are javascript dialog). So I have create a simple 300px X 200px Div in html with two button (Yes or No). I return true on click on Yes. and false on No. ----But My code does not wait for my answer it execute below code.----- This is my problem.. Thanks in advance write me back if not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Write your ask function to accept two functions (one for yes, one for no):

```
function abc(){
    var ans  = ask(function(){
                   do_action();
               }, 
               function(){
                   refuse_action()
               }); /// contain html custom confirm with button
}
```

Such a simple yes/no case does not warrant the overhead of writing it with jQuery promises, but that is another option. (see UweB's answer).

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `$.Deferred()` in jQuery.
In order for this to work, your functions will have to return a `promise`.

Without going into detail, this is the general structure you're looking for:

```
function showDialog() {
    var ret = $.Deferred();

    // Render your confirm dialog, and show it
    // The 'OK'-button needs to call ret.resolve();
    // Call ret.reject() when the user clicks 'Cancel'.

    return ret.promise();
}
```

The calling function has to do the following:

```
function callingFunction() {
    var x = showDialog();

    x.done(function() {
        // Put the code to be executed when the user clicks 'OK' in your dialog.
    });

    x.fail(function() {
        // Put the code to be executed when the user clicks 'Cancel' in your dialog.
        // You can omit hooking the .fail() function up, if you don't need to do anything.
    });
}
```

For more information, take a closer look at the [description of the idea behind $.Deferred()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/), and also the [$.Deferred API](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function abc(){

     ask(function() { 

                do_action( function() { 

                     refuse_action();

                });
        }); 

}

abc();
```

Comment: This does both the true then the false action. The asker wanted to choose between the two actions based on user input (from `ask()`).

Comment: ya I agree your point. Thanks you are right.

Answer (score 0):

Read about callback functions;
http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/